# Order of column in composite partitioning key

Tags: cassandra, scylla

I am using Scylla database and I have created a partitioning key composite of two columns.
Does the order of keys matter in this case?

Table definition

```
create table X(
user_id text,
city text,
name text,
PRIMARY KEY ((user_id, city))
);
```

will anything change if I write

`PRIMARY KEY ((city, primary_key))?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a composite partition key the order does not matter.

Switching the order of the keys may result in different hash values. But it shouldn't reduce the efficiency of data distribution.

Comment: ^ provided the underlying codebase is Apache Cassandra® as I'm not sure how scylla db works and I'm afraid that's not the case here

Comment: @Madhavan Good point.  My answer is predicated on partitioning using the Murmur3 hash algorithm.  Similar to Cassandra, Scylla uses a Murmur3 partitioner as its default, which suggests that it would behave in a similar manner.